# Raspberry Pi 2 - HDMI not displaying

Tags: power, hdmi, power-supply, usb-power, pi-2

Just recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B 1GB. I also bought a micro SD card Kingston 16GB Class 10. I loaded up the Noobs software as instructed on: https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/

The issue I am now having is the green light on the Pi stays on solidly and the red light flashes, but on my Toshiba 32inch TV, the HDMI feed doesnt seem to be recognised. TV will time out then turn off. I have swapped HDMI cables and tried on a different TV to no avail.

I have also tried another SD card and this time there was no blinking red light, but there was still no HDMI sign of life. Each time I have tried, I have noticed that my USB ports dont seem to be getting any power as my USB mouse light doesnt come on (same with keyboard).

Before I splurge on a new Power Supply, is the HDMI problem most likely linked to this? And is it advisable to use a: http://www.amazon.co.uk/NorthPada-Supply-Charger-2000mA-Raspberry-Black/dp/B00MTX9GD8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1430172197&sr=8-1&keywords=raspberry+pi+2+power+supply

Instead of my PS4 Micro USB cable plugged to a USB power supply.

Comment: Are you plugging in the HDMI prior to booting the Pi? I have had some issues with hot-plugging and HDMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue ended up being my SD card wasnt configured properly. I had been using LinuxLive CD creator but when I tried the same process with Win32DiskImager. Life came to this little Pi of mine!

Power Supply was also changed to a regular Samsung charger.